# QtQuick Project exe issue in release mode

Tags: qt, release, qml, qt-quick

I have worked with VC++ project during my past days. Whenever the project is build in release mode or debug mode, the exe runs itself without any additional dependencies. We just have to click on the exe, and the project runs.

But this is not working in QML project. I have both debug & release desktop versions of project, but they are not running on clicking the exe.
Do we need some additional component to make a sort of wrapper for exe to make it run.

I would like to mention that I'm not asking regarding the deployment of QtQuick application.

Comment: Qt is seperated into modules such as Gui, Core, Webkit, Declarative etc.Since this is a QML Project it needs the QtDeclarative library file to execute properly. Just add the QtDeclarative.dll to the folder where your exe file resides. You can verify this link http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/deployment-windows.html for further information on deploying Qt Windows application. You are not asking for deployment but still the steps will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You should add some dlls:
    QtCore4.dll QtCored4.dll QtGui4.dll QtGuid4.dll

Comment: I did so...but still its not running. Do we need to make changes in the .pro file for the same

Comment: Does your 'mainwindow' just not show or the system reports some errors?

Comment: Main window appears to be blank with default dimensions. And no error report is generated

Comment: Does it give any responses? Or just crashes when you click it?

Comment: Only the default main window appears and then it becomes unresponsive.

Comment: I actually do not know what happens behind, but I have experienced this before, it was because uninitialized table column count set to a table widget, the uninitialized int value may be 1000,000 or more, but the ui cannot draw so many columns within a size-limited widget. You can imagine how narrow each column will be... May this be helpful for you:) Good luck!